# How do well informed labels for ordinal encoding improve model performance?

Tags: categorical-data, encoding, performance

From Kaggle's [intermediate machine learning](https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexisbcook/categorical-variables?scriptVersionId=79127496&cellId=13) tutorial, it was stated that

> for each column, we randomly assign each unique value to a different integer. This is a common approach that is simpler than providing custom labels; however, we can expect an additional boost in performance if we provide better-informed labels for all ordinal variables.

Here's what I understood:

If I had a column named `place` with the unique values being `[first, second, third]`, then I would get better performance by encoding those as `[1,2,3]` compared to `[2,1,3]`. Is my understanding correct? If so, how does this lead to better performance? Since the integers are just used as a numeric placeholder for the unique values, does the ordering even matter as long as those integers can uniquely identify each value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I had a column named place with the unique values being [first, second, third], then I would get better performance by encoding those as [1,2,3] compared to [2,1,3]. Is my understanding correct?

Yes, your understanding is correct.

> If so, how does this lead to better performance? Since the integers are just used as a numeric placeholder for the unique values, does the ordering even matter as long as those integers can uniquely identify each value?

There is a confusion between:

- the actual meaning for a human of these integers in this particular case -> in this sense yes, they are just used as a numeric placeholder
- how these values are interpreted by a ML algorithm, e.g. classifier -> the ordering *does matter* for the algorithm, it considers these values as numerical and treat them like any other feature.

The second point implies that the algorithm may use a condition `v>=2`, this could cause overfitting if the ordering doesn't make any sense.

For the record I don't understand the logic of this part of the tutorial: to me an ordinal variable has by definition an order which is assumed to be known, it doesn't make sense to use `OrdinalEncoder` on the wrong order. It looks like they are talking about using `OrdinalEncoder` on some categorical variable (sometimes done to avoid high number of features with one-hot encoding) or some variable of unknown type, maybe?

Comment: Thanks! For your last point, you are right. At one point, the tutorial mentioned that one-hot does not work well when the categorical variable takes on a large number of values. They discarded all columns with >=10 unique categorical values, then compared the performance between ordinal encoding and one-hot encoding. One-hot performed better in this case.

Comment: @Terrarium ok thanks, it's similar to what I suspected. This is a matter of opinion actually, but personally I prefer to encode categorical variables as OHE even with large number (and 10 is not large imho). But it's true that if the number of values is *really* large it can cause problems (curse of dimensionality). In such a case I would rather try to remove the least frequent values first (replace with a default value), this is often enough.